# LinkedIN Way to prevent Linkedin Oauth expires after 60 days

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have a website where people can post blogs. I want the blogs to be automaticly posted to a Linkedin account connected to the website. So the person posting the blog is not the owner of the linkedin account.

I use the Sharing API from LinkedIN to do this, but this requires the administrator of the linkedin account to refresh the Oauth token every 60 days. I know this is a security thing to prevent illegal use of accounts. But in this case its always my own linkedIN account. Is there a way around this? mabe by using the app key and secret instead of the acces token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LinkedIn API docs (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens) say:

> In the case the access token is already expired, your application will
>   go through the same authorization flow as previously described.
>   However, the login dialog will be shown to the user as they will need
>   to grant access to your application again.

so there's no way around that. But what you could do is go through this flow **before** the access token has expired. The docs say:

> Simply have your application go through the authorization flow in
>   order to fetch a new access token with an additional 60 day life span.
>
> When the following conditions exist:
>
> User is still logged into Linkedin.com The current access token isn't
>   expired (within the 60 life span) We will automatically redirect the
>   user back to your redirect_uri without requiring them to reauthorize
>   your application. If they don't exist, we'll prompt them to login and
>   then redirect them.

Comment: This is the normal procedure, for if the owner of the linkedin account wants to post a blog to its profile. But we want the 'Random user' to post to our own linkedin account.

Comment: Yes, the owner of the LinkedIn account (you) should make sure that he updates the access token stored in the app backend every 59 days. For sure you cannot do this through the "random user"'s browser.

Comment: I was already afraid that was the only answer. Thanks for confirming!